# Creating a thread-safe queue balancer

Tags: python, thread-safety, python-multithreading

My project involves processing images for clients en mass. Clients send image files zipped up, which fires off ImageMagick command-line scripts per image. The problem I am trying to solve is that if these commands are queued in the order I receive them, then a client that needs to process 10k images will hog all resources for hours. My solution is to round-robin each client's queues, so that everyone slows each other down equally. I have created this class to implement this:

```
class QueueBalancer():
    def __init__(self, cycle_list=[]):
        self.cycle_list = cycle_list
        self.update_status()

    def cmd_gen(self):
        index = -1
        while True:
            try:
                if self.cycle_list:
                    self.processing = True
                    index += 1
                    commands = self.cycle_list[index]["commands"]
                    if commands:
                        command = commands.pop(0)
                        if len(commands) == 0:
                            del self.cycle_list[index]
                            index -= 1
                        self.update_status()
                        yield command
                else:
                    yield None
            except IndexError:
                index = -1

    def get_user(self, user):
        return next((item for item in self.cycle_list[0] if item["user"] == user), None)

    def create_or_append(self, user, commands):
        existing_user = self.get_user(user)
        if existing_user:
            index = self.cycle_list.index(existing_user)
            self.cycle_list[index]["commands"] += commands
        else:
            self.cycle_list += [{
                                      "user"     : user,
                                      "commands" : commands
                                   }]

    def update_status(self):
        if next((item for item in self.cycle_list if item["commands"] != []), None):
            self.processing = True
        else:
            self.processing = False

    def status(self):
        return self.processing
```

As you can see from the else clause of `create_or_append()`, the `cycle_list` is a list of dictionaries like this:

```
{"user": "test1", "commands": ["command1", "command2"]},
{"user": "test2", "commands": ["x", "y", "z"]},
{"user": "test3", "commands": ["a", "b", "c"]}
```

(real commands removed, sample strings used)

A single instance of `cmd_gen()` will be used to feed commands into my shell, and I will use `create_or_append()` to add in users and commands on-the-fly, while commands in the queue are still being processed. This seems to work great so far in my initial tests, but is this theoretically thread safe? If not, what would I need to do to make sure it is?

Comment: A side note - you shouldn't use mutable default arguments as you can get some unexpected side effects: `def __init__(self, cycle_list=[]):` - ref http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/gotchas/#mutable-default-arguments

Comment: Ah, I knew that felt weird when I wrote it. Thanks for the tip

Comment: This might be simplified by turning `cycle_list` into a dict that maps user onto the commands list. The dicts with "user" and "commands" keys doesn't do anything.

Comment: Thinking about this, I think round-robining the user jobs might be slightly painful, as to do it 'correctly' I think you'd need to do quite a lot of bookkeeping with regards to when users get added/removed from the list. Depending on your use case, it may be feasible (and will def. be simpler) to choose a random user each time and process their first job?

Comment: I don't see any threading in your code, so it's hard to judge if it is thread-safe.

Comment: I did it this way to maintain a predictable order, so that the round robin works. I looked into OrderedDicts, but my initial research indicated there is extra complexity involved with making them thread safe.

Comment: If it's not too long, I'd like to see how your threads use this class

Comment: You don't need threading code to tell that it's not thread safe.

Comment: You are right, but it is in order to know if you really need to use some `Lock` on your methods. I ran a lot of projects with `threading` library, and I always feel that `Lock`, `Queue`, `Event`, `Condition` etc are pretty slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought I'd have a shot at creating a generic balanced queue like you described - here's the result. I think there are still some pathological cases where a user could have many jobs processed sequentially, but it would involve other users jobs being added a specific times/orders, so I don't think it would happen in the real works and couldn't be exploited unless multiple users colluded.

```
from threading import Lock


class UserBalancedJobQueue(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self._user_jobs = {}
        self._user_list = []
        self._user_index = 0
        self._lock = Lock()

    def pop_user_job(self):
        with self._lock:
            if not self._user_jobs:
                raise ValueError("No jobs to run")

            if self._user_index >= len(self._user_list):
                self._user_index = 0
            user = self._user_list[self._user_index]

            jobs = self._user_jobs[user]
            job = jobs.pop(0)

            if not jobs:
                self._delete_current_user()

            self._user_index += 1
            return user, job

    def _delete_current_user(self):
        user = self._user_list.pop(self._user_index)
        del self._user_jobs[user]

    def add_user_job(self, user, job):
        with self._lock:
            if user not in self._user_jobs:
                self._user_list.append(user)
                self._user_jobs[user] = []
            self._user_jobs[user].append(job)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    q = UserBalancedJobQueue()
    q.add_user_job("tom", "job1")
    q.add_user_job("tom", "job2")
    q.add_user_job("tom", "job3")
    q.add_user_job("fred", "job4")
    q.add_user_job("fred", "job5")

    for i in xrange(3):
        print q.pop_user_job()

    print "Adding more jobs"
    q.add_user_job("dave", "job6")
    q.add_user_job("dave", "job7")
    q.add_user_job("dave", "job8")
    q.add_user_job("dave", "job9")

    try:
        while True:
            print q.pop_user_job()
    except ValueError:
        pass
```

Thinking more about it, an alternative implementation would be to remember for each user when their last job was run, and then choose the next user based who's last job was the oldest. It would probably be more 'correct' but it would have the (probably negligible) extra memory overhead of remembering last job time for every user.

Edit: So it's a slow day - here's that other approach. I think I prefer it to the above, though it's slower due to O(N) search for the user with the oldest previous job.

```
from collections import defaultdict
from threading import Lock
import time


class UserBalancedJobQueue(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self._user_jobs = defaultdict(list)
        self._user_last_run = defaultdict(lambda: 0.0)
        self._lock = Lock()

    def pop_user_job(self):

        with self._lock:
            if not self._user_jobs:
                raise ValueError("No jobs to run")

            user = min(
                self._user_jobs.keys(),
                key=lambda u: self._user_last_run[u]
            )
            self._user_last_run[user] = time.time()

            jobs = self._user_jobs[user]
            job = jobs.pop(0)

            if not jobs:
                del self._user_jobs[user]

            return user, job

    def add_user_job(self, user, job):
        with self._lock:
            self._user_jobs[user].append(job)
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a doubt on the thread-safety of the following part :

```
def create_or_append(self, user, commands):
    existing_user = self.get_user(user)
    if existing_user:
        index = self.cycle_list.index(existing_user)
        self.cycle_list[index]["commands"] += commands
    else:
        self.cycle_list += [{
                                  "user"     : user,
                                  "commands" : commands
                               }]
```

If 2 threads run the method `create_or_append`, there's a possibility for the 2 threads to be in the else closure, and then corrupt a little bit your data. Maybe defining a lock could be a good idea on this function.

```
from threading import Lock

class QueueBalancer():

    def __init__(self, cycle_list=None):
        self.cycle_list = [] if cycle_list is None else cycle_list
        self.lock = Lock()

    # .../...

    def create_or_append(self, user, commands):
        with self.lock:
            # ...
```

EDIT: as said @matino, you can also have some issue with the `update_status` function, because it modify the `processing` instance attribute. I would recommand to use another lock on it in order to ensure it is thread safe.

```
def update_status(self):
    with self.update_lock:
        if next((item for item in self.cycle_list if item["commands"] != []), None):
            self.processing = True
        else:
            self.processing = False
```

Answer (score 1):

Your class is definitely not thread safe, since you mutate its instance attributes:

- In `update_status` you mutate `self.processing` value
- In `create_or_append` you modify `self.cycle_list`

  Without a locks on these attributes your class won't be thread safe.

**Side note**: always initialize all your instance attributes in the `__init__` method. Since you use `self.processing` in your code, it should be in the `__init__`